# Why is it 一つ、二つ、三つ　「の」？

Tags: particle-の

Why do the counting words use a possesive particle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think の is strictly a possessive particle when addressing quantities, much like the functionally overloaded に and で.

In Japanese, you can use counting words as prefix: 500グラムのバター or suffix: バター５００グラム, so it acts more like a connective than a possessive particle anyway.
If you look at 「全てのバター」 ("the butter of all" = all the (blocks of) butter) vs. 「バターの全て」 ("all of the butter") you might even /feel/ that there is a difference, though I think that difference is too obscure to make use of it.

Possessive particles are well-defined on (a subset of) the domain of (NP,NP), e.g. 「家族の友達」 and have their syntax reused for other domains, e.g. 緑の花 (the flower of green), 一個のパン (the bread of one).

It is possible to think of の as a substitute topic marker (は). Such is the reasoning for these phrases:

[相手の日本人 or 日本人の相手?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/%E7%9B%B8%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA-or-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%B8%E6%89%8B?rq=1)

[What is the role of の in 「お父さんのバカ!」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/what-is-the-role-of-%e3%81%ae-in-%e3%80%8c%e3%81%8a%e7%88%b6%e3%81%95%e3%82%93%e3%81%ae%e3%83%90%e3%82%ab%e3%80%8d?rq=1)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow- even in the NP NP case の can mean possesion or something like は、 but I've never been taught that other meaning and it *isn't* は、can you explain in a different way?

Comment: Saying 家族の友達 can mean the family's friend,  or the family that is a friend right?

Comment: Or 医者の友達、 can't it mean the doctor's friend or my friend that is a doctor right?

Comment: @Tony: 1. which example? 2. yes and yes 3. yes and yes.
Let me point out that the interpretation as possessive is one of many that の can have. Look at 「子供の本」: "the book of the child(ren)", "a book for children", "a book by children", "a book made out of children...", these are all valid interpretations of the connective. The same interpretation you arrive at if you simply read "children-book" in English (because juxtaposition is heavily overloaded).

Comment: So is the only way to know via context?

Comment: Yes of course. This is the bane of all natural languages and Japanese as a second language in particular :)